# jQuery id select in ASP.NET content page

Tags: jquery, asp.net, content-pages

Here is my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function () { 
    $(".div_question").toggle(function () { 
        var answer= "answer" + $(this).attr("id"); 
        $("xxx").slideDown(); //  what could i write here.
    }, function () { 
        var answer= "answer" + $(this).attr("id"); 
        $("xxx").slideUp(); 
    }); 
}); 
</script>
```

and here is my content page:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater_question" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource_question"> 
 <HeaderTemplate> 
 </HeaderTemplate> 
 <ItemTemplate> 
     <div> 
         <div class="div_question" id='<%# Eval("question_id") %>'> 
               <strong><%# Eval("question_header") %></strong> 
         </div> 
         <div class="div_answer" id='<%# "answer"+Eval("question_id") %>' style="display: none; padding: 5px 5px 5px 15px;"> 
              <%# Eval("question_content") %> 
         </div> 
     </div> 
 </ItemTemplate> 
</asp:Repeater>
```

I want select `div_answer` to show / hide.  What I write instead of "xxx", I cant find correct syntax.  In the master page, when I write `$("#" + answer)` it works.  But, in content page, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on your markup structure you can just use `next()` and be done with it. `next()` finds the immediately following sibling optionally filtered by a selector.

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    $(".div_question").toggle(function () { 
        $(this).next().slideDown();
    }, function () { 
        $(this).next().slideUp(); 
    }); 
});
```